# From which table does for all enteries makes a select?

Tags: sql, abap

I have two standard tables, `VBAP` and `MAKT`.
I want elements of MAKT-MAKTX, where MAKT-MATNR = VBAP - MATNR.

```
SELECT MATNR FROM VBAP INTO IT_VBAP.

SELECT MATNR MAKTX FROM MAKT INTO IT_MAKT FOR ALL ENTRIES WHERE MATNR = IT_VBAP.
```

Does this code choose values in it_makt where only those matnr fields are equal?

What exactly does for all entries does.

Thank you.

Comment: Add some sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: Is there a special reason for not using a JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

```
 select field_1 field_2 field_n from table into internal_table for all
 entries in another_internal_table where some_field_in_table = another_internal_table-same_field_in_another_internal_table.
```

You use for all entries when you want to fill an internal table according to values in another internal table.

You can try using the following

```
select matnr from vbap into it_vbap.
select maktx from makt into it_makt for all entries in it_vbap where matnr = it_vbap-matnr.
```

Comment: Don't. This is wrong. See http://scn.sap.com/thread/1174072 for a detailed explanation.

Comment: @vwegert. I am still learning ABAP.Can you please point out why is this wrong.

Comment: @gaurav-seghal Assuming that you have read the conversation I referred to, which part of it specifically is unclear to you?

Comment: @vwegert. The conversation points out that using `joins` is better than using `for all entries`.But that does'nt make the above code wrong.Does it?

Comment: Why it's always a spirit of being a cop for everything in this channel. Man, that is wrong, The question was specific 'What exactly does for all entries does.'. Of course we all aim to answer a question however we should be also be constructive in our appreciations. If we think that the question or answer lacks of something isn't it better to comment or post a better answer related to that question or answer? We are here to guide and give the best orientation not only to askers but to everyone here. Personally I perceive it as arrogance and very disrepectful to answer with an ironical question

Comment: I appreciate better answers.Even i am learning.I only wanted to know whether my suggestion works or not.I appreciate the link and went through  it and understand that the better way is to go use `joins` but what i wanted to know was whether my approach would work or not.Better solutions are always welcome.

Comment: @NelsonMiranda You might observe that I've asked why the OP didn't use a join, and I have not received an answer. Personally I perceive it as disrespectful not to answer follow-up questions that might lead to more helpful answers. "I'm still learning" should not be abused as an excuse to lean back and let others do the work (which I tend to see in a lot of ABAP entry-level questions, both here and on SCN). And I'm trying to keep my tone down, at least compared to some of the SCN moderators.

Answer (score 0):

For all entries is the the exact thing, You might think, as You read it. It is like this:

"For all entries in" allows You to use a subset of an internal table as where condition in a select statement by the possibility to provide the fields of this internal table as where condition-parameters in the select statement.

So, internally it is also only a loop, You can use the sql-monitor transaction, and mostly will see, that for all entries really  behaves like a select inside a loop if I remember correctly. It is quite helpful, and usually used relatively often.

If the subset-table, which is used as parameter-table is empty, then You perform a full table select (full table scan), if You only use the tables fields as where parameters. So always pay attention to the select which fills Your where-table or check its contents with  `if lines( the_table ) > 0.` Nevertheless take a look at vwegert's link, it describes the pros and cons of for all entries. Do You need more info ?